How to hide the installing package message from the executed powershell command in the .bat script?
How to hide the blue pop-up notification "installing package AudioDeviceCmdlets" and "Downloaded" messages from the executed powershell command in the cmd window?

I see this when I use the powershell command straight from the .bat script:
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Install-Module -Name AudioDeviceCmdlets" -Force >NUL 2>&1

Ultimately, I would like everything to happen silently, without additional messages and notifications popping up.
I tried changing the content of the command and its order and tried various other switches such as -Confirm:$false, -Out-Null, -Hide, -Silent, -Quiet etc. and I didn't what I needed.
The only thing I managed to do is -WindowStyle Hidden, where it hides the entire CMD window after executing the command. I don't want that!
Can I add another condition, change a command or switch to improve it?
I need powershell code to be run directly from cmd.exe, a powershell prompt or script is not useful to me.

Have a look here

Using the source offered by Theo via comment, (thanks), everything now looks like this and works perfectly:
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; Install-Module -Name AudioDeviceCmdlets -Force" >NUL 2>&1

